# Deducing type of template value parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-variables

I was wondering if the type of a value template parameter could be deduced or obmitted when writing something similar to this:

```
enum class MyEnum {A, B}

enum class MyOtherEnum {X, Y}

template <typename T, T value>
struct GenericStruct {};
```

When using `MyGenericStruct` both `T` and `value` have to be passed, but `T` would be deducible from context `typename T = decltype(value)` except that `value` is not yet defined. `template <auto value>` isn't working either.

Is there any way to simply write `MyGenericStruct<MyEnum::A>` instead of `MyGenericStruct<MyEnum, MyEnum::A>` without usage of macros?

Comment: "`template <auto value>` isn't working either." why not?

Comment: apperently because I had c++11 active. works with c++17 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use C++17, you can use `auto` as the type of the non-type template parameter.  That gives you

```
template <auto value>
struct GenericStruct {};
```

Now, `value` will have its type deduced by its initializer just like if you had declared a variable with type `auto` and gives you the desired syntax of `GenericStruct<MyEnum::A> foo;` as seen in this [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/dfTnEvfxx).